# Проверить массив на совпадение

Tags: java, android-sdk

Пытаюсь проверить  массив res и внести те значение которых нет в массиве id , это 200 и  75, но как это сделать не могу понять

```
ArrayList<String> ok_ = new ArrayList<>();
        String res [] = {"97", "200", "108", "33", "75"};
        String id [] = {"23", "45", "97", "33", "95", "108", "56"};

        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

            for (int k = 0; k < id.length; k++) {

                if (!res[i].equals(id[k])) {

                    ok_.add(res[i]);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: [как проверить содержит ли массив значение](https://www.programcreek.com/2014/04/check-if-array-contains-a-value-java/)

Comment: проверять наличие элементов одного массива в другом - дело неблагодарное. ваши массивы несортированы, это значит, что решение - перебор во вложенном цикле, а это очень плохой вариант. тут возникает вопрос: как вы умудрились в бизнесс-логике получить 2 массива для их сравнения. чем руководстовались, выбирая в качестве структуры данных именно массив? но если ситуация действительно патовая (эти массивы даны "свыше"), то я бы искал другое решение, например, перебросил данные одного массива в сет.

Comment: а если значение не в массивы занесены  в ArrayList<String> res  и ArrayList<String> id

Comment: Тогда смотрите в сторону `list.retainAll()`